# Compiling Lua - create .so files?

Tags: linux, lua, makefile, centos, dynamic-library

I am compiling Lua 5.2.3 on Centos 6.5, and the compilation / install works fine.

However, I also need the development libraries for another program to compile. I would usually install these by doing this :

```
yum install lua-devel
```

Problem is that installs the Lua 5.1 shared libraries, not the 5.2.3 ones.

I *could* just run with Lua 5.1 from the Centos repo, but if it's a simple-ish thing (for someone who knows) to make the latest version work then I'd be grateful for someone showing me the way. For me the Linux makefiles are still a little bit er, well, you know...

EDIT

I found this site - http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2006-10/msg00091.html - from a long time ago which suggested some changes to the makefiles, but I get this when i run them now :

```
gcc -fPIC -o liblua.so -shared lapi.o lcode.o lctype.o ldebug.o ldo.o ldump.o 
lfunc.o lgc.o llex.o lmem.o lobject.o lopcodes.o lparser.o lstate.o lstring.o ltable.o 
ltm.o lundump.o lvm.o lzio.o lauxlib.o lbaselib.o lbitlib.o lcorolib.o ldblib.o 
liolib.o lmathlib.o loslib.o lstrlib.o ltablib.o loadlib.o linit.o
/usr/bin/ld: lapi.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `luaO_nilobject_' can not be used 
when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

noting that I added the -fPIC in a futile gesture; that wasn't suggested in the link just hinted at in the error.

EDIT 2 - SOLUTION

Ok, whilst I'd found this mod myself originally, it was catwell's assurance that it worked that led me to persevere. Here's what I did...

From [catwell's link](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/liblua.so.patch?h=packages/lua) I manually edited the Makefiles. It's easy enough to follow (and as catwell suggests, ignore the luaconf.h mods).

The missing link is to change the following line :

```
src/Makefile
------------
CFLAGS= -O2 -Wall -DLUA_COMPAT_ALL $(SYSCFLAGS) $(MYCFLAGS) -fPIC
```

You are adding the -fPIC to the end.

Seems to work fine now.

Thanks to Etan, but I'm accepting catwell's answer as it led most directly to the solution.

Comment: Can the person(s) who down voted the question please say why? First time it's ever happened to me and I'm curious as to what I did wrong.

Comment: You need -fPIC on the ld call too.

Comment: It's so much easier to just compile Lua from source into your program. Lua itself is tiny, the target won't have linker issues when building (no issues with the wrong Lua version being installed), and your program can choose it's own compile-time flags for Lua.

Comment: This was for Asterisk which looks for the libraries to link to. Any deviation from that build process would have been beyond me I'm afraid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look how [Arch Linux does it](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk?h=packages/lua). You should not touch `LUA_ROOT` but the rest of the patch is good and relatively simple to understand.

Don't forget to add `-fPIC` to the CFLAGS too (the Arch package [does it here](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/lua#n36)).

Comment: Hi - I still get the same error :
gcc -shared -ldl -Wl,-soname,liblua.so. -o liblua.so. lapi.o lcode.o lctype.o ldebug.o ldo.o ldump.o lfunc.o lgc.o llex.o lmem.o lobject.o lopcodes.o lparser.o lstate.o lstring.o ltable.o ltm.o lundump.o lvm.o lzio.o lauxlib.o lbaselib.o lbitlib.o lcorolib.o ldblib.o liolib.o lmathlib.o loslib.o lstrlib.o ltablib.o loadlib.o linit.o -lm
/usr/bin/ld: lapi.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `luaO_nilobject_' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
lapi.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Ahah! I added -fPIC to the compile line (the right one at last) and it worked! Thanks to this guide (which is a slight variation on the one I found). I'm editing the post to show what I did.

Comment: The patch is really bad because it's trying to build a shared library but doesn't bother to create a set object files with position independent code.

Comment: @maxschlepzig The package sets the CFLAGS, including -fPIC. https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/lua#n36 Editing my answer to make this clear.

Answer (score 4):

The lua team does not include support for shared libraries by default because doing so in a portable manner is not simple. If you get the srpm for lua from CentOS you should be able to find within it the modifications they make to the lua build process to generate the shared objects that they package and ship. CentOS srpm's live on vault.centos.org.

Comment: I found the src rpm [here](http://vault.centos.org/6.5/os/Source/SPackages/) but could find nothing in the makefiles that created the .so files. I'm assuming the -devel installed libraries are compiled differently, but I can't find a source rpm for that. I might have to consider this beyond my reach and go back to 5.1.

Comment: The -devel package is a sub-package of the main package. There is only one srpm for all of them. You want `lua-5.1.4-autotoolize.patch` from the srpm for the record. It patches the stock build files to include the necessary autotool magic to build shared libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, but after running that patch the slender grip I had on the original makefile was lost to the complexity of the resulting files.

Comment: And you begin to see why the lua team doesn't include it by default. The patch is unfortunately complicated because it is applying the output of the autotool process to the existing system and not just including the minimal parts necessary to bootstrap the process. The bits you need to understand are the .am files, configure.ac, and the autogen.sh file.

Comment: Thanks, Etan. But I'm completely out of my depth here. I was hopeful someone may have done it and could easily show me how, but it doesn't matter. It's obviously too complex for me.

Comment: The Arch solution is a simple non-portable solution which will work on the systems for which it is designed for. Which is why arch can do that so directly, they aren't concerned with excessive portability. The autotools are so their solution is more complex (also they cover a much larger range of things than just shared library building).

Comment: +1 for introducing me to the rpm sources and teaching me something new.

Answer (score 2):

@beigerac's answer works for lua-5.3.0 also.  But, it's just compiling the `liblua.so.5.3.0` and establishing symlinks inside `lua-5.3.0/src`.  When doing a `sudo make install` it is not copying the `.so` files to `/usr/local/lib` like it probably should.  So, I added onto the patch so it copies the .so files into place.

For lua-5.3.0, these patch files worked for me:

[Makefile.patch](https://gist.github.com/899047f3a2d603b25a58.git)

And, for src/Makefile:

[src/Makefile.patch](https://gist.github.com/6095183b8dc60c909779.git)

Copy the patch files to lua-5.3.0/ and lua-5.3.0/src (respectively) and apply the patches like this:

```
cd lua-5.3.0/
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dcarrith/899047f3a2d603b25a58/raw/7fa41ee5c0113ed721abe979c269afe48472baf5/Makefile.patch -O Makefile.patch --no-check-certificate
patch -l < Makefile.patch
unexpand Makefile > Makefile.unexpanded
mv Makefile.unexpanded Makefile

cd src/
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dcarrith/6095183b8dc60c909779/raw/614d769d5b70b69b5d67cfb618696bfb906e2aca/src.Makefile.patch -O Makefile.patch --no-check-certificate
patch -l < Makefile.patch
unexpand Makefile > Makefile.unexpanded
mv Makefile.unexpanded Makefile
```

The `unexpand` lines are to make sure any spaces that may have been put into place with the patch are converted to tabs so the `make` won't complain with the error `missing separator`.

Comment: Tested with lua-5.3.3, works (although the Makefiles had to be manually edited, the changes were basically the same). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No need to patch anything. Just tell make your extra cflags

```
lua-5.3.5$ make MYCFLAGS="-fPIC" linux
```